# Pop notification in airplane mode

Tags: java, android, notifications, alarmmanager, airplane-mode

Is there any way to show the notification from alarm manager while the phone is in airplane mode?

I'm working on an app that uses the background service to display notifications and is testing the ability to display notifications in airplane mode. Is it possible?

Comment: yes, its possible to show notification in airplane mode, why not? enable such mode, then start playing some music in any player (e.g. VLC) - it will show `Notification`

Comment: programmatically?

Comment: is there any other way for showing `Notification`? if you know any please share